# Superset ImportError: No module named psycopg2

Tags: apache-superset

I am getting the following error when trying to connect to a postgres db in superset

> ImportError: No module named psycopg2

I have install psycopg2 with pip and restarted the superset by still getting the same error. any idea?

Answer (score 1):

If you are running superset inside a virtualenv, try to install psycopg2 at system level.
Also, install psycopg2-binary package.

Answer (score 0):

As stated above, you may have installed superset in a virtual environment as suggested in the install guide (https://superset.incubator.apache.org/installation.html#python-virtualenv)

A good indicator is to search for where you installed superset and if it's in a folder `venv`, it's likely in the virutal environment.

You need to ensure that the python packages are installed in your virtual environment as well.  Installing on your local computer will not work.

Go to where you installed superset (in my case /Applications/venv/), and activate the venv:

`. venv/bin/activate`

Install your packages
`pip install psycopg2`